# How to place folders above the files in Project Exporer in STS 2.9.0 (Eclipse Indiglo)

Tags: eclipse, ide, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm using: SpringSource Tool Suite Version: 2.9.0.RELEASE Build Id: 201203011000.
Can someone tell me how can I fix the mess I've got in Project Explorer, which is all items are sorted alphabetically despite of them being file or folder. Take a look at the screenshot I've attached.

I'll appreciate your help, thanks![image]

Comment: Have you tried hitting `F5` aka right click -> refresh? Refreshing might trigger resorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several bug reports out there that indicate that this is caused by some plugins, e.g. *CDT* or *M2E*. I see that you're using *m2e-wtp*, that might be one of the reasons.

Have you tried the *Package Explorer* or *Navigator* views? They shouldn't change the order.

Ticket references:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=270103
- http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/533287/

Comment: Thanks, I've switched to Package Explorer although it doesn't show all SVN stamps next to files names.